# Pull in email of assigned_user_id in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, email, sugarcrm

I am completely new to working with SugarCRM.  I am working on a project that has a custom extensions for SugarCRM.  They then pull data from this extension using the API to another part of the site.

In this extension they are calling in this variable `$assigned_user_id`

I need to modify the extension so that I can also pull in the **Email address** of the user assigned to `$assigned_user_id`

Can any Sugar experts point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be to pull it directly from the Sugar database itself.

If you have any knowledge of `SQL`, it should be pretty easy with a `SELECT statement`. Let me know if you need an example.

As far as pulling the email with the API itself, look here:
[Sugarcrm.com](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100REST_API/100Examples/100PHP/Retrieving_a_list_of_records_-_REST_and_PHP)

You'll need to define the email field and you need to make sure you are actually returning and setting the `assigned_user_id`